# Show children in a ListView in EntityTemplates

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4

I'm very new to asp.net, but I found setting up a scaffolded website for an existing database is super simple. I have it up and running.

Making things work the way I want is a bit more tricky.. I have a `Customer` table with a one-to-many relationship with the `ContactMoment` table. By default the detail view of `Customer` show a link to view the `ContactMoments` (which is defined in the `FieldTemplate` called `Children` by default). What I would like is to include a `ListView` of all the `ContactMoments`.

I tried the following:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="DynamicControl2" DataMember="ContactMoment" />
```

This does not work. I probably need to use the `DataSourceID`, but I have no idea how te retrieve that from the current entity. Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks :)

**Update**: I just found [Dynamic Data Extensions](http://ddextensions.codeplex.com/) which lists the following interesting bit. (unfortunately the project seems abandoned..)

> 1. **ChildrenList** – Provides a way to show child tables, works in conjunction with the new Edit and Details page templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an extra datasource and Listview Control to get the result you want..

I haven't tried this Code but it should work... make changes to Entity names according to your actual Names..

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="ContactMomentDataSource" runat="server"  
        ContextTypeName="YourEntities" EnableFlattening="False"  
        EntitySetName="ContactMoment"  
        Where="@CustomerID IN (SELECT VALUE Customer.CustomerID FROM it.Customer  AS Customer)"> 
        <WhereParameters> 
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="YourDetailView" Type="Int32" Name="CustomerID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" /> 
        </WhereParameters> 
    </asp:EntityDataSource>

<asp:ListView ID="ContactMomentListView" runat="server"  
        DataSourceID="ContactMomentDataSource" 
        AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        SelectedRowStyle-BackColor="LightGray"  
        DataKeyNames="ContactMomentID"> 
        </asp:ListView>
```

Now you just need to add Column you want to display in Listview's markup..

Hope this helps...

Comment: I'm not sure what to fill in for _YourDetailView_. This all is to be implemented in the `EntityTemplateUserControl` of Customer. `EntityTemplateUserControl` has no `SelectedValue` however.

Comment: well, I don't know which control you have used for Displaying 'Customer' Table..By default its use DetailsView.This Control's id will be 'YourDetailView'. And Instead of EntityTemplate you should use Custom PageTemplate... [This article might help you](http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2008/07/dynamic-data-and-custom-pages.html)

Comment: It works now, I found out that I can retrieve the currently selected entity object ID from the `FormView` in `PageTemplates\Details.aspx`.

Comment: Why would you suggest using custom PageTemplates? I only wanted to change the template of the entity Customer.